# File upload is not working in server but working locally

Tags: apache, file, file-upload, php

I have seen my phpinfo file,it has no tmp value set 
so I set it to 
/tmp

```
upload_tmp_dir = "/tmp"
```

But still it is not working.
My server is in Amazon ec2.

I have tried putting the upload_tmp_dir as "/var/www"  (with no trailing slash ) ,but that too didn't work.
Do I need to set permissions to the tmp directory ?

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

is giving

```
enter code here
Array ( [upload_file] => Array ( [name] => ps.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpBcpdfP [error] => 0 [size] => 193728 ) )
```

and

```
 is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'])
```

is giving the result 1

Comment: Do you have folder permission?

Comment: What  does examining the `$_FILES` variable tell you?

Comment: Array ( [upload_file] => Array ( [name] => ps.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpBcpdfP [error] => 0 [size] => 193728 ) ) @Oswald.

Comment: @EdwinAlex /tmp is set to root.

Comment: So `$_FILES['upload_file']['error']` is equal to `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` and `move_uploaded_file()` still fails when called on `$_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']`?

Comment: yes move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], $file_name) is not working ONLY in server,but working locally @Oswald

Comment: And what does [`is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'])`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-uploaded-file.php) return?

Comment: 1 it shows on echo @oswald

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25362/discussion-between-madhu13-and-oswald)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a permission issue on the destination folder.

Do `sudo chmod -R 777 /destination/folder` and try again. Then it should work. If you still can't upload your file, maybe the permission problem is on a parent directory.

After that, find which user (and its group) is the owner of your uploaded file.

Then set the permission back, and change the owner of your directory : `sudo chown -R owner_user.group /destination/folder`.